# Deploy Angular app outside Angular environment

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm trying to create an app in Angular 7, following the tutorial that gives you the default page

```
ng new my-app
```

I already reviewed it with `ng serve --o` and it works, but I have no idea now how to pass it to an environment outside of Angular. I've done

```
ng --build --aot = true
```

This has created a folder `/ dist / my-app` and 3 JS files come in: main.js, polyfills.js and runtime.js I opened the index.html but nothing is shown, I expected to see the same thing I was doing in development.

I tried to run them with node, doing for example `node main.js` but it has not worked, in the 3 options it says

window is not defined

Has anyone already done these deploys to see how it would be in production?

What am I doing wrong....

Comment: `... opened the index.html but nothing is shown.` <= You are likely getting an error in the browser. Open the browsers debug window and look at the console output. What is the error. Include the error(s) in the question or, better yet, search on the error message and see if you can figure out the solution based on the error.

Comment: Wow @Igor I got an error loading all the JS files, I don´t know why the browser is looking for them in C:/ I moved the files, only the files co C:/ and it worked,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps built with `Angular` or similar frameworks such as `React` or `VueJs` needs to be deployed in a **weserver**. Simply opening the `index.html` file in the browser will not work.

Now there are several ways of doing this -

## Development

You can use [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)

```sh
npm install http-server -g

http-server -p 8080 ./dist
```

You can visit http://localhost:8080 to view your server

## Production

There can be several options for production deployment depending upon a variety of factors such as your cloud provider, web server etc. The following two are an example -

1. [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/products/hosting/)

Firebase has a very simple deployment step - do `firebase init` once and `firebase deploy` to deploy your newly built webapp.

2. You can use *Nginx* running in [docker](http://docker.com)

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY build/ /var/www
```

Answer (score 1):

what you must do is mount your **dist folder**, which is the result of the **ng-build** you made on any http server.

apache: copies the dist folder in the www/html path of your apache